# jquery - how to make a dialog box when user clicks a link?

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I want to know that how to make a dialog box that popsup when user clicks a link like if i click send then a dialog box popsup to tell that your information has been sent!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Twitter Bootstrap modal...
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Popup](http://jsfiddle.net/nfNEZ/1/).Please check it out and let me know if it helped you.

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui , try to start accepting answers also , by doing this people will be more interested in helping you.Also check for alternative answers , mine might be working , but some other answers might be better.